# Win8challenge.com showing a Yellow Screen of Death

Tags: bug, status-completed, windows-8-challenge

[Win8challenge.com](http://win8challenge.com) seems to be showing ASP.net's YSOD.

Can a dev please take a look?

---

Seems like the site's down again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be back up shortly (if not already as I type this).

Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: yep, it's up now. Thanks!

Comment: its back down :(

Comment: @JourneymanGeek So it is... Might take a bit longer to sort out. Not sure if anyone's still around at this hour.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Aaand... up again. Might be something intermittent. We're looking into it.

Comment: I haven't been able to access it for the last three hours if that helps :P

Comment: Seems to be still down.

Comment: The site is still down.

Comment: It's back up now.

Comment: Currently getting a Runtime Error